# If I have created a new tag, will I be the moderator for that tag

Tags: discussion

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags), I understand that anyone having points more than 1500 can create a new tag. My question is If I have created a new tag, will I be the moderator for that tag or  who will be handling all question in the tag.

How does it work? Will I be the one responsible for all the question related to that tag if I create that tag?

Comment: While 1500 is the required rep on Stack Overflow, only 300 rep is required on Drupal answers: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags

Comment: ok I did not know that one, Thanks :) @FreeRadical

Comment: I just discovered this question while preparing a variation of this question (hang on, I'll ask it soon) ... Please edit the title of this question to match the actual question, which is "If I have created a new tag, will I be the moderator for that tag?" ... I just wanted to edit the question myself, but for some (not-yet-clear-to-me) reason I was not allowed to use the "edit" link ... Next question: why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags are just that, tags. **There is no tag-based responsibility, or tag-based permissions.** Everyone is responsible for moderation of this site, using tools he earned access to: flags, close and reopen votes, and so on.

The only use of tags is to make questions easier to find, or easier to ignore. For example, my settings are:

[image: My favourite and ignored tags]

It means that questions tagged as [form-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-api), [jquery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery), [javascript](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript), and [ajax](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax) will be highlighted, as ones I may have more to tell in them, and [organic-groups](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-groups), [accordion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accordion), and [administrator](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/administrator) will be greyed out, to discourage me from speaking where I know my experience is limited.

This does not change the fact that I *am* supposed to vote to close if I see off topic question, no matter if it's  [form-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-api) or [accordion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accordion). And no matter if I was creator of any of these tags or not.

## TL;DR

Being tag's creator changes nothing.

Comment: so it means If I make a new tag `mytag` and I am seeing a question off topic for `mytag` then I am the only one allowed to close that question ? or any one with sufficient amount of point can close it ?

Comment: @hitesh If **anyone** sees question off-topic, he should vote it off-topic. If anyone sees question miss-tagged, but still on-topic on the site, he should edit to remove inappropriate tag. Anyone can do that, given that he 1) has high enough reputation and 2) wasn't banned from that specific action.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense :)